# Change font size in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Here below:

My Windows Forms application have functionality to change language, but my problem is that when my application in English fonts look much finer than in Hindi fonts.

Below is the screen shot of my application in both the Hindi and English language.

#### Hindi Font

[image: Hindi]

#### English Font

[image: English]

Comment: What kind of Windows application? Your tag says [tag:asp.net], but that is more for Web applications. And you don't have the screenshots linked to properly.

Comment: i am not getting you... what kind of windows application? means..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not change the font size within a MessageBox. The MessageBox font size is defined by the user's operating system.

The only way you can do this, is by creating your own custom Message Box:

> [How To Make a Custom Message Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221806/messagebox-show-fonts#3222164)

To change the Windows Forms form font, just use the Form's **Font Property**:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(
                      "Microsoft Sans Serif",
                      24F,
                      System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                      System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                      ((byte)(0)));
    }
}
```

Replace "24F" with the desired font size.

Comment: but did not need to change the font of message box i need to change the my form font..

Comment: Maybe by using the `Form.Font` property ?

Comment: Hm. I believe the problem is that the OP wants different font sizes for different languages.

Comment: @KrunalMevada No, that is a Windows system property. You can't chnge that from within a program.

Comment: No, unless you customise the window completely, that is, draw everything in it yourself. See, for instance, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460/custom-titlebars-chrome-in-a-winforms-app).